# "no database selected" error even query is fine

Tags: php

I am new to mysql and php. I am working on database programming with php with mysql but getting "no data base selected" error continuously. I found this error quite famous on internet. I tried every answer which were given to others having the same problem but nothing worked.
Here is my code:

```
if(!@mysql_connect('localhost','root','') || !@mysql_select_db ('a_database') ){
     die ('Connection Error !');
  }


$query = "SELECT `food`,`calories` FROM `food` ORDER BY `id`";

if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){

while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
{
        $food = $query_row['food'];
        $calories = $query_row['calories'];

        echo $food.' has '.$calories.' Calories'.'<br>';

}

} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

This is the code that gives error. After some search on net. I made some bit of changes, but the result was same.
Changes that I made to first 3 to 4 lines:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$link || !mysql_select_db ('a_database', $link) ){

      die ('Connection Error !');
}
```

Please tell me what should I do to get rid of this problem, Thank you.

Comment: `mysql_*` is outdated, please use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Why do you have an OR statement between `$link` and `mysql_select_db`, and what is with all the `!`, its definitely not easy to read.

Comment: sorry, but it is not my own style. i am following a thenewboston tutorial.

Comment: @ConnorTumbleson Um, `!` is the least problem here. Anyway, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Panique: what should i do then?

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz You are following bad tutorial. Read the manual ([`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/)) first almost everything is covered there.

Comment: If a tutorial still teaches `mysql_` functions, **you will learn bad things from it**. Stop and find a better source. Try http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: The code you have provided cannot produce the error "no database selected". Have you confirmed that the error comes from _exactly_ the code in your question?

Comment: Alright fellows, i am gonna switch. but what about this one? there must be a solution for this one.

Comment: yes exactly, it comes from my code.

Comment: I'm guessing you already checked that all the values (username,password,database_name,host) are all correct?

Comment: yup they all are fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","a_database");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you do as follow, `$query_run=mysql_query($query, $con);`

Comment: Hi @MuhammadFaraz,   plz check mysqli_select_db reference with examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n"; // if everything is successful
```

And yes don't use mysql_* as it's deprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: As said... don't use `mysql_*` because it's outdated. Use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Comment: In regards to the first edit, assigning the identifier variable to the connection information is not needed, but it's recommended to sucessfully handle multiple connections to multiple databases

Comment: @Amit Malakar: i got following output after adding your code: 
"localhost via TCP/IP No database selected"

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz:  in mysql.ini file check defined port it should be 3306.

Comment: @AmitMalakar I found this line there:
"Version: '5.6.12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)"

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz: do you get this "Failed to connect to MySQL: " along with the "localhost via TCP/IP no database selected" or just the error msg